# Communication between two agents using mainclass initialization

Tags: agents-jade

Jade Agent communication not working 
I'm new to jade programming; I'm trying to understand agent communication

I've tried using arguments window to start agent and it works that way however when I call in agent from my main class
The response isn't getting through

Agent initialization

```
AgentController agentCtrl = mainCtrl.createNewAgent("MasterAgent", MasterRoutingAgent.class.getName(),new Object[0]);               
AgentController agentCtrl2 = mainCtrl.createNewAgent("DeliveryAgent", DeliveryAgents.class.getName(),new Object[0]);

        //start agent
        agentCtrl.start();
        agentCtrl2.start();



//Send message from main Master Agent
ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.CFP);

            msg.setContent("Master Agent Initialization Complete");
            msg.addReceiver(new AID("Message Initiate"+AID.ISLOCALNAME));
            send(msg);





//Reciever Agent
addBehaviour(new CyclicBehaviour(this) {

            @Override
            public void action() {
                System.out.println(getLocalName()+": Waiting for Message");
                ACLMessage msg = receive();

                if(msg!=null) {
                    System.out.println(getLocalName()+": Recieved Response from "+ msg.getSender().getLocalName()+" message: "+msg.getContent());

                }
                else if(msg==null){
                    System.out.println("This is a null message");
                }


                System.out.println(getLocalName()+": This line is printed");
            }

        });



The agent doesn't recieve the message
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your receiver AID is correct? Maybe you should write `msg.addReceiver(new AID("DeliveryAgent", AID.ISLOCALNAME));`